# Store the nmServerStatus () result in a variable in python

Tags: python, weblogic12c, nodemanager

I am writing a python file which checks the current status of weblogic server and perform the required action(start/stop).

I am using nmServerStatus to get the status of weblogic status.
How can I store the the result of nmServerStatus in a variable ?

it's syntax is nmServerStatus (ServerName).

Let me know if any other information required.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just try ? :

```
adminServerStatus= nmServerStatus('AdminServer');
if( adminServerStatus != 'RUNNING'):        
...
```